# Python question about overridden/redefined imported function as Class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython, class-method, pep8

In https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/518c4be6ae16f1e00bfd55781171da91282b340a/Bio/SeqUtils/ProtParam.py I have this importing statement:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import molecular_weight
```

and then in a class:

```
class ProteinAnalysis:

.....
.....
    def molecular_weight(self):
        """Calculate MW from Protein sequence."""
        return molecular_weight(
            self.sequence, seq_type="protein", monoisotopic=self.monoisotopic
        )

......
......
```

What is this type of coding called? Is it normal to call imported function and class method with same name?

To my knowledge, `self.molecular_weights` is not equal to `molecular_weights`, but why call them the same? Is that PEP 8 compliant?

Would

```
a = ProteinAnalysis()

print(a.molecular_weights == molecular_weights)
```

give `True` or `False`?

What about:

`print(a.molecular_weights(*args,**kwargs) == molecular_weights(*args, **kwargs))`

Comment: modified question in " Is it pep8 compliant ?" to avoid other close votes

Comment: Why not try the code yourself? It seems easy to test if they would return true or false

Comment: Did it, see my example below. More interested if there is a a wording for this kind of eponymous functions/methods  where you import a function to create a same name object.method that return object loaded *args ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is normal as there is no contradiction. You cannot freely get access to any class attributes even in methods inside a class. For example, let's look at this:

```py
var = 5

class SomeClass:
    var = 6

    def show(self):
        print(var)

SomeClass().show()
```

The result is `5`. As there is only one "variable" `var` in global scope.

If we unlink it via `del var`, we will get `NameError`:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [38], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 SomeClass.show()

Input In [37], in SomeClass.show()
      5 def show():
----> 6     print(var)

NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

But you can get free access during the class initialisation:

```py
class SomeClass:
    var = 6
    print(var)

    def show():
        print(var)
```

Hereinabove code prints `6`.

In **Biopython** code only the imported function is used because the calling is inside a method where there is no direct access to the class attributes. Moreover, the method even is not initialised at the moment.

`a.molecular_weights == molecular_weights` gives `False` because even if they do the same they are different objects: a method & a function.

`molecular_weights() == a.molecular_weights()` would give `True`, if the same arguments are sent.

There is no contradiction with PEP8 naming rules as both do the same but one is a function, other is a method of appropriate class and objects.

Comment: I fail to see how your example code even relates to what the OP is asking...

Comment: @Alexander To my mind, the question was about name scope inside a class and how confounding it is to use the same names for methods and functions, wasn't it?

Comment: Yep. To me, as a novice to coding & python, took a, ittle  to figure-out how the molecular weight is calculated in Biopython. And was wondering if this approch was dictated by particular reasons like efficiecy, correct coding design and so on. To me was actually confounding that same name was chosen. Still dont understand why to import function from.outside to be loaded with self attributes ? Is it related to APi decision @Alexander was talking about ? Bur I am a loss here  since I dont know what API stands for in this contest, always associated API in relation to web servers, my bad.

Comment: @Alexander , if you have time to spare could you have a look at the example a posted below to check if it is rigt in respect to my question above ?

Comment: @Vovin , if you have time to spare could you have a look at the example a posted below to check if it is rigt in respect to my question above ? –

Answer (score 1):

> **"What is this type of coding called"**

This appears to simply be an API decision.  I don't know if there is a special name for it or not.

> **"Is it normal to call imported function and class method with same name?"**

"normal" isn't exactly a well defined, so instead I will suggest there is nothing unusual about it.

> **"To my knowledge, self.molecular_weights is not equal to molecular_weights, but why call them the same?"**

When supplying the same parameters to the `molecular_weights` function, the result will be the same value.  And as mentioned earlier this is what was decided when building the API.

> **"Is that PEP 8 compliant?"**

Probably.

> **"would `molecular_weights == a.molecular_weights` be True"**

No

> **"would `molecular_weights() == a.molecular_weights()` be True"**

No, molecular_weights has required parameters so this would raise and exception.

But this would return true:

```
molecular_weights(a.sequence, seq_type="protein", monoisotopic=a.monoisotopic)  == a.molecular_weights()
```

Whoever wrote the code wanted the ProteinAnalaysis instances to have the molecular_weight function as part of its method API.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example I made to answer my question above:

in a folder named `modul` I have `__init__.py` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def pippo():
    
    print('pippo')
    
    return 5
```

in the same dir where `modul` folder is , I have `run.py`

```
from modul import pippo

print(pippo, type(pippo))

class pluto():
    
    print(pippo, type(pippo))
    
    def pippo(self):
        
        print('redefined')
        
        print(pippo, type(pippo))
        return pippo()
    
    
a = pluto()

a.pippo()

print('a.pippo() --->   ', a.pippo(), type(a.pippo))

print('fun == : ',a.pippo  ==  pippo)

print('fun() == : ', a.pippo()  ==  pippo())

print('type(fun) == : ', type(a.pippo)  ==  type(pippo))

print('type == : ' , type(a.pippo) ,  type(pippo),' == : ',  type(a.pippo) ==  type(pippo))

print('id : ', id(a.pippo)  ,  id(pippo), ' id : ', id(a.pippo)  ==  id(pippo))
```

result:

```
<function pippo at 0x7fcaa27a30d0> <class 'function'>
<function pippo at 0x7fcaa27a30d0> <class 'function'>
redefined
<function pippo at 0x7fcaa27a30d0> <class 'function'>
pippo
redefined
<function pippo at 0x7fcaa27a30d0> <class 'function'>
pippo
a.pippo() --->    5 <class 'method'>
fun == :  False
redefined
<function pippo at 0x7fcaa27a30d0> <class 'function'>
pippo
pippo
fun() == :  True
type(fun) == :  False
type == :  <class 'method'> <class 'function'>  == :  False
id :  140508326858176 140508286038224  id :  False
```

of course in my question `molecular_weights` needed *args, **kwargs while my example show a function that just return an `int`

So again to me its like the imported function is returned loaded with class attributes, and I get that point, but why calling the method that returned that with same name ?

Comment: Because they do the same actions. Data processing via applied methods to them is the basis of OOP. It is expected behavior that `molecular_weight` returns a molecular weight of a polypeptide sequence in `ProteinAnalysis` object. There are a lot the same eponymous functions/methods in, for example, `numpy`, `pandas` &c.